# Actual signing flow is not what configured in template

Tags: docusignapi

We have a template has the following signing flow:
[flow we want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEIsp.png)

Below is how we send the parameters:

```
{
"emailSubject": "Test company - Custom Rates Letter",
"emailBlurb": null,
"status": "sent",
"templateRoles": [
    {
        "roleName": "Paticipant B",
        "name": "Paticipant B",
        "email": "paticipantB@example.com"
    },
    {
        "email": "paticipantA@example.com",
        "name": "Paticipant A",
        "roleName": "Paticipant A"
    }
],
"templateId": "xxxxxxx-yyyy-zzzz-aaaaa-bbbbbbbbb"
}
```

However, the actual flow we get is not what we configured in the template. It's as followed:
[flow we actually get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjzjJ.png)

We want participant A to receive 3 copies: (1) the original unsigned contract (2) the contract signed only by participant B (3) the contract signed by all parties. However, participant A only receives (1) and is not able to receive (2) and (3).

I have tried many other parameters but all don't work. Could you give me some help on this? We want the actual flow to be the same as the flow configured in template. Thanks.

Comment: why you want to put same recipient again and again in the routing order? to let him/her know that envelope has progressed?

Comment: Yes. That's what we want. @Amit K Bist

Answer (score 1):

DocuSign does not support this type of workflow, i.e putting same roleName at different places. You need to have different roleName (eg, Participant A1, Participant A2 etc) in your Workflow, then pass same Recipient Name/Email for each roleName.

Or if you want to put same recipient multiple times in the workflow just for notification, then I would request you to consider using [DocuSign Connect](https://support.docusign.com/guides/connect-guide), once you receive an XML message from DocuSign on your subscribed event then send an email from your Email Server to the concerned person with the notification details.